# Get initial key values from children in Firebase using completion handler IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I'm looking to get the number of keys, and then key values from a list of previously set data in Firebase.  I'm trying to fully comprehend completion handlers, however I may not be there yet.  Why does this return an empty array?  Or at least doesn't populate with data before the next function (outside of this code) runs?  Thanks!

```
//Initial data download from Firebase
func getKeys(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {

    Database.database().reference().child("food").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            //Get count of how many child "apples"
        Let childApplesCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        //Get each key
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            print("keys in snapshot: \(key)")

            //Append to an array of keys for later use
            self.onloadKeyArray.append(key)
        }

      }

    completion()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the completion call is outside of the closure for the database call, so it gets called right away before the data is returned. If you move it into the closure, you will be able to access the information when you want it. This [blog post I wrote](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html) may help give you some better insight into handling closures.

```
func getKeys(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    Database.database().reference().child("food").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        //Get count of how many child "apples"
        Let childApplesCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        //Get each key
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            print("keys in snapshot: \(key)")

            //Append to an array of keys for later use
            self.onloadKeyArray.append(key)
        }
        completion()
      }
}
```

Furthermore, if you will need this data outside the closure, it would be a good idea to pass it to the completion handler, like this:

```
func getKeys(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {

    keyArray = [String]()
    Database.database().reference().child("food").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        //Get count of how many child "apples"
        Let childApplesCount = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)

        //Get each key
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            print("keys in snapshot: \(key)")

            //Append to an array of keys for later use
            keyArray.append(key)
        }
        completion(keyArray)
      }
}
```

Then when you call the function, you'll have the array. This enables you to separate your data functions from your view controllers.

```
yourClass.getKeys() { keyArray in
   self.keys = keyArray
}
```